# Azure Devops - parse version into .nuspec file

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, nuspec

How can I parse the specified version from the .yaml file to the .nuspec file?

Here are the important parts of the .yaml file

```
variables:
    solution: '**/*.csproj'
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    version.MajorMinor: '1.0'
    version.Revision: $[counter(variables['version.MajorMinor'], 0)]
    versionNumber: '$(version.MajorMinor).$(version.Revision)'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    inputs:
        command: 'pack'
        packagesToPack: '**/*.nuspec'
        versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
        versionEnvVar: 'versionNumber'
```

.nuspec file

```
<?xml  version="1.0" ?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>Project</id>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <description>Project description</description>
        <authors>Me</authors>
    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file  src="bin\**\*.dll"  target="lib"  />
    </files>
</package>
```

I'm using the .nuspec file so that I can include some other .dlls in the NuGet package. How can I parse the `versionNumber` variable to the .nuspec file using `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task?

Comment: The ` versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'` should do the trick. try to edit the `version` in the nuspec file to `<version>$version$</version>`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk When I change `1.0.0` to `$version$`, the build fails and the logs shows two error message. 1. `An error occured while trying to parse the value '' of property 'version' in the manifest file` and 2. `Value cannot be null or an empty string. (Parameter 'value')`

Comment: @spovelec Did you ever get a solution to this? I have the same requirement and can't seem to pass the value to the nuspec file myself

Comment: @user1474992 Unfortunately, no. I abandoned the idea of trying to use .nuspec files. I wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XmlTransformV1@0` task to override `versionNumber` in your Pipeline:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzhukovsky.xml-transform

Build defenition:

```yaml
- task: XmlTransformV1@0
  inputs:
    folderPath: '**/*.nupkg'
    targetFiles: '*.nuspec'
    overrides: 'package.metadata.version = 1.2.3'
```

Release definition:

[image]